# How do I get all string literals in a Ruby source code file?

Tags: ruby, code-analysis

I'm analyzing some code and I'm looking for string literals, to check if I have any duplicates. For example, if I have

```
def test_foo
  input_filename = "foo.txt"
  # ...
end

def test_bar
  input_filename = "bar.txt" # Fine
  # ...
end

def test_baz
  # Bad! Refactor it to a constant that's shared by test_foo and test_baz
  input_filename = "foo.txt" 
  # ...
end
```

I want the analysis program to tell me that `["foo.txt", "bar.txt", "foo.txt"]` exist in my source code.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't forget the `%q` and `%Q` versions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install [ruby_parser or parsetree](http://parsetree.rubyforge.org/ruby_parser/), you'll be able to do something like this (assuming that the program text is in `text`):

```
result = RubyParser.new.parse(text)
result.flatten.to_a.select {|elt| elt.is_a?(String)}
```

(This could obviously be nicer, but it should be enough to get you started!)

Comment: Thanks! PS: `result.flatten.grep(String)` is one way to code golf it.